# Jquery clone cloning same instead of new name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

I currently on development with cakephp. I didn't have a lot experience with jquery but in this task ,I want to clone a input/select field for a form using jquery .clone() function. I already do the script but it's didn't work as I thought . I really don't know how to solve this problem even after googling.

the problem is:
I have this type of input `name="data[item][0][name]"` ,
I want to clone this input and increase the 0 value++ like this

```
     name="data[item][0][name]"
     name="data[item][1][name]"
     name="data[item][2][name]"
```

what have I done is when I clicked the add attribute button,
it will replace and copy same integer value like this:

if I clicked the add button once  :

```
name="data[item][1][name]"
name="data[item][1][name]"
```

I clicked the add button again:

```
name="data[item][2][name]"
name="data[item][2][name]"
name="data[item][2][name]"
```

it copy same name instead of increase the value.I really don't know what is the problem.please guys help me.

this is my code:
PHP:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-lg-2" style="padding:none;" >
                                    <p style="">Attribute</p>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="addAttribute"><i class="fa  fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Attribute</button>
                                </div>
                                <?php $options = $attribute; //fetch some data from db?>
                                <div class="row" style="">
                            <div class="col-md-9" style="" >
                                <div class="col-lg-3" style="" >
                                    <h5 align="center"><u>Attribute Name</u></h5>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <div class="col-lg-12">

                                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('attribute.0.attribute_id',array('class'=>'form-control','label'=>false,'id'=>'Attribute','options'=>$options));?>
                                    <div id="CloneAttribute">

                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-3" style="">
                                    <h5 align="center"><u>Attribute Value</u></h5>
                                    <div class="form-group">

                                      <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('attribute.0.attribute_value',array('class'=>'form-control','label'=>false,'id'=>'Attribute2',));?>
                                <div id="CloneAttribute2">

                    </div>  
                                </div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    index = 0;
    $("#addAttribute").click(function(){
        index++;
     $("#Attribute").clone().attr("id","Attribute" + index)
        .appendTo('#CloneAttribute');
        //For each input fields contained in the cloned form...
         $('#CloneAttribute').each(function(){
            $('#CloneAttribute select').attr("name",'data[attribute]['+index+'][attribute_id]');                    
         });
});
```

Thank you stackoverflow..

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    index = 0;
    $("#addAttribute").click(function () {
        index++;
        $("#Attribute").clone()
        .attr("id", "Attribute" + index)
        .attr("name", "data[item][" + index + "][name]")
        .appendTo('#CloneAttribute');
    });
});
```